# Trouble installing Rails mysql2 on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows

Things were going find and dandy, creating an app in Rails. Then I pulled an app my boss built, had to run the bundler, and now I'm out of business. Tried various things without success, now thinking I should re-install Rails. A problem with connecting to MySql seems to have developed from pulling my bosses app. Any help with the following error message would be appreciated.

```
Q:\source\ahistory>gem install mysql2
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.3
.17 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/mys
ql2-0.3.17/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Seems like you lack the programs to build a native C extension for the sayd gem. You could try MinGw or similar programs.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Rails. I do have a mingw folder in Ruby and don't have a 'sayd' gem folder. so I'm assuming MingGw is being used? How would I find out if MinGw, and not sayd, is being used?

Comment: This is where it fails (from mkmf.log): cc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/i386-mingw32

Comment: Could you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483436/error-installing-pg-gem-on-windows   It talks about PG gem but the process of getting it on the system is pretty similar.

Comment: Also take not how he installs the gem in hes question. He does it seperatly without using bundle at first. And also he uses options to show where the compiler and other stuff are. Installing database gems on Windows is a complicated hassle in my opinion. I have gone throught it too when trying to get Rails environment working on coworkers computers. That is why I my self prefer Linux systems when working with Rails atleast.

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen. It looks like the gem install could not find the mysqlconnector in the devkit. I added --with-mysql-dir <path> and I'm back in business.