# Cloned GitHub Ruby repo, but not able to start it locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

Downloaded RoR app from github by cloning, ran bundler.io to install all the dependencies, but when I run rails server, get the below error, thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Do you have all the required gems installed?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Postgres installed and running

Make sure your database is in place

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is certainly that you've not got the [`pg` (PGSQL)](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home) gem installed.

After Ruby 2.2, you can run Rails without the required gems; you end up with a multitude of errors about missing files etc. This appears to be one of them, although we don't run `pgsql` in dev, so I could be wrong.

--

Since you're using Windows, you'll have to download PGSQL and get the appropriate dependency files. [Here's a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483436/error-installing-pg-gem-on-windows):

> 1. [Download PGSQL](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload)
> 2. Run `gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir="c:/path/to/pg/sql"`
> 3. If this installs, you're good to try `rails s` again

The most important thing to consider is that Windows uses different dependencies to Linux / Mac OS. I've not got the experience to tell you what those differences are; I can say that with "integration" gems (`mysql2`,`rmagick`, `nokogiri`, `pg`), Ruby will require you download & reference the correct libraries in order to get the gem installed.